# how to get values of columns for a selected row through jQuery on click of element calling method to retrieve value

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i am trying to fetch values of a particular column for a selected row via jquery.In Following code i have two rows which do not have any id.I tried following way and getting both rows value for that column appending each other.how to get value for that row only using jquery only.I want to call test function on click of that element, dont want to use http://jsfiddle.net/SSS83/

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function test(){
var id = $(".use-address").closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
  alert(id);
}
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<table id="choose-address-table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
  <thead>
    <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
      <th>Name/Nr.</th>
      <th>Street</th>
      <th>Town</th>
      <th>Postcode</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr"><span>50</span>

      </td>
      <td>Some Street 1</td>
      <td>Glas</td>
      <td>G0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="use-address" onclick="test();">Use</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="nr"><span>30</span>
      </td>
      <td>Some Street 2</td>
      <td>Glasgow</td>
      <td>G0 0XX</td>
      <td>United Kingdom</td>
      <td>
          <button type="button" class="use-address" onclick="test();">Use</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use jQuery Click event!!

Any way, if you want to stick with your test function, you need to tell the function from where it got called.

so change the

```
<button type="button" class="use-address" onclick="test();">Use</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="use-address" onclick="test(this);">Use</button>
```

And update your **test** function as

```
function test(el) {
    var id = $(el).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
    alert(id);
}
```

Enjoy!!

---

If you change your mind you can use the following code

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {
        jQuery('.use-address').on('click',function() {
            var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(2)').text();
            alert(id);
      })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on a click of a TD:

```
$('td').on('click',function() {
      //get the column of the TD
      var myCol = $(this).index();

      //loop through the rows of this table, get the TD in the same column
      $(this).parent('table').find('tr').each(function() {
         var colValue = $(this).find('td').eq(myIndex).html()
      }
})
```

"colValue" in the loop will grab the contents of the TD at that position.

Comment: need to add above piece of code into test function ?

Comment: No. It uses the actual click on the TD to determine which column is selected.